# Batch File Copy All Users Profile App Data

Tags: batch-file

We are having a batch of new PC's currently we backup the local profiles by hand. I have written a script to backup the main files of each user profile however someone pointed out that our users use sticky notes and want those backed up too.

While Testing my code I used:

```
XCOPY "C:\USERS\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes" %Input%\%computername%\AppData\ /Y
```

I am aware this will only copy the person logged on at the time. I did try using a `*.*` in place of %username% but got no luck. Is there a way I can copy each users .snt file into a folder named with their username?

%Input% is the external drive letter & Colon (Example E:) input by the technician who is doing the backup.

Comment: You might be interested in `for /D %%D in ("C:\USERS\*") do xcopy /Y "%%~fD\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes" "%Input%\%computername%\%%~nxD\AppData\%%~nxD\` (use `%` instead of `%% if typed directly in command prompt); I added a directory level at the destination showing the username...

Comment: @aschipfl can you submit this as the answer, that worked brilliantly. Thank you for such a quick asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards like `*` and `?` can only be used at the lowest level of a path, so `C:\USERS\*.*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes` does not work. However, `C:\USERS\*` works.

So you can use `for /D` to walk through all the user directories, like this:

```
for /D %%D in ("C:\USERS\*") do (
    xcopy /I /Y "%%~fD\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\*.snt" "%Input%\%ComputerName%\%%~nxD\AppData"
)
```

I appended the pattern `*.snt` to the source path as you mentioned such files in your question.

I also added a directory level `%%~nxD` in the destination path which is the name of the currently iterated user, to avoid trouble with duplicate paths.

Finally I added the `/I` switch which tells `xcopy` that the destination is a directory, to avoid such prompts.

To use the above code directly in command prompt, write it like this:

```
for /D %D in ("C:\USERS\*") do xcopy /I /Y "%~fD\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\*.snt" "%Input%\%ComputerName%\%~nxD\AppData"
```